# Dynamic Hyperlink in Table Issue

Tags: excel, dynamic, hyperlink

I am working with a Table inside of excel. I would like to have it so the number documents in the table are hyperlinks back to my file folder.

I am finding that the Hyperlink formula will not work in the table. Using the same formula outside of a table it seems to work.

I have the below formula in the hyperlink link_location:

`=LEFT(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("[",CELL("filename",A1))-1)&
INDEX(Sheet2!$H$3:$I$19,MATCH(LEFT([@Number],1),Sheet2!$H$3:$H$19,0),2)&
"\"&[@Number]`

In the above code;
The first part of the code identifies the file location.
Index in the code returns the name Processes for P for the Number (P009).

Returns: R:\Integrity Management\2. Document Control Management\Processes\P006

Error window coming up says: Cannot open specified file.
Ultimately it would be great if the "Number" items would hold the hyperlink instead of a separate column.

[Current table set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWcIp.png)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why. The links are currently working as intended today. If anyone has a reason why this issue occurred please let me know.